# Rails: Authlogic: Cannot update user attributes -- "Password field cannot be blank"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, authlogic

I've got a simple form on a User page that allows a User, once they have logged in, to change some attributes on their own user object. The view:

```
<% form_for @user, :url => {:controller => "teachers", :action => "update"} do |f| %>
    <%= f.error_messages %>
    <%= f.text_field :display_name %>
    <%= f.submit "Update" %>
<% end %>
```

I need to supply the URL because it is not a standard RESTful controller. The controller provides

```
@user = current_user
```

to the view.

Next, the `update` action in the controller tries to handle the save:

```
@user = current_user
if @user.update_attributes(params[:user])
  flash[:notice] = "Successfully updated profile."
  redirect_to root_url
else
  render :action => 'edit'
end
```

This should update the `display_name` attribute on the `user` object, save it to the database, and redirect to the root_url. Instead, the `edit` action gets rendered again with the form's error_messages indicating that the "password can't be blank."

This is clearly something that Authlogic is messing with! Ack! Here's a look at my entire `Users.rb` file:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  acts_as_authentic do |c|
    c.transition_from_crypto_providers = Authlogic::CryptoProviders::MD5
    c.crypto_provider = Authlogic::CryptoProviders::Sha512
    c.validate_email_field = false
    c.require_password_confirmation = false
    c.ignore_blank_passwords = true
    c.validate_password_field = false
  end

  belongs_to :school

  validates_presence_of :first_name, :last_name, :email, :password
  validates_uniqueness_of :email, :scope => :email, :case_sensitive => false, :message => "is already in our database. Please contact us for help reactivating your account."

  ROLES = %w[admin teacher student]

  def role_symbols
    [role.to_sym]
  end
end
```

As you can see, I've turned off most every Authlogic validation I can find in order to keep this simple and functional! Still no luck. If I add a `password_field` to the edit page then it will work successfully -- but it will also update the user's password when this form is intended only to update their `display_name`!

Any tips on how I can update the attributes on a `user` object without having to pass in the user's password?

Comment: Please show us your current model.

Comment: Thanks for your patience, Trevoke. I just managed to figure it out! Adding the entire model to my question gave me a chance to go back and experiment with other potential pitfalls... it turns out that Authlogic was not the problem at all.

The problem was my `validates_presence_of` that was firing whenever I updated my user object. I added an `:on => :create` stipulation to the validation, and now it is all working just fine.

I still don't understand why that validation wasn't complaining about `:first_name`, `:last_name`, or `:email` not being included, but hey -- it works now! Thanks again.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It turns out the problem was not with Authlogic. The problem was my `validates_presence_of` that was firing whenever I updated my user object. I added an `:on => :create` stipulation to the validation, and now it is all working just fine.

Comment: The problem with this solution is that if you have multiple attributes for your User, and you attempt to update one of the other attributes while leaving the password fields blank, you will actually be changing your password to "". Ideally you have a way to not update the password if the fields are left blank.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this?

```
validate_password_field = false
```

Comment: Tried it! No luck. Still getting `Password can't be blank`.